# PostgreSQL: Using schema and table names from other tables?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

Consider the situation where I have all my schema names in one table and all my table names in another table.

Is it possible to do something like in the following (pseudo-code)?

```
SELECT value FROM (SELECT schema_name FROM schemas).(SELECT table_name FROM tables)
```

Or do I have to break up the query into three SELECT's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jack has demonstrated the way to go. However, I feel there is room for improvement.

Test setup:

```
-- meta tables for schema and table name    
CREATE TABLE schma(schma_id int, schma text);
INSERT INTO  schma VALUES (1, 'x');

CREATE TABLE tbl(tbl_id int, tbl text);
INSERT INTO  tbl VALUES (1, 't1'), (2, 't2');

-- dummy tables to be used in example query:
CREATE TABLE t1(id int);
INSERT INTO  t1 VALUES (1),(2);

CREATE TABLE t2(foo text);
INSERT INTO  t2 VALUES ('some text'), ('some more text');
```

Function updated with `format()` in 2017; formatted in 2021:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynaquery(_schma_id int
                                     , _tbl_id int
                                     , _col text
                                     , _type anyelement)
  RETURNS TABLE(col anyelement)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
      'SELECT %I FROM %I.%I'
    , _col
    , (SELECT schma FROM schma WHERE schma_id = _schma_id)
    , (SELECT tbl   FROM tbl   WHERE tbl_id   = _tbl_id)
   );
END
$func$;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_dynaquery(int, int, text, anyelement)
IS 'Query any column from a dynamically assembled tablename.
$1 .. id of schema
$2 .. id of table
$3 .. name of column
$4 .. type of column (only data type matters, not the value)';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a487c390a5c098a938f64cca9bc5136d)*

Call:

```
SELECT col FROM f_dynaquery(1, 1, 'id', NULL::int);
  col
-----
   1
   2

SELECT col FROM f_dynaquery(1, 2, 'foo', NULL::text);
  col
----------------
 some text
 some more text
```

The function can return **any column of any type**.
Read the manual about [Polymorphic Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) and [Declaring Function Parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS).

Use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to defend against SQL injection. See:

- [PL/pgSQL regclass quoting of table named like keyword](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141113/pl-pgsql-regclass-quoting-of-table-named-like-keyword/141680#141680)

Retrieve the table name by query as requested.

Name the returned column, so it is easier to reference.

#### Original answer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynaquery_old(int, int, _col text, _type anyelement, OUT col anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
   SELECT ' || quote_ident(_col) || '
   FROM   ' || (
       (SELECT schma FROM schma WHERE schma_id = $1) || '.' ||
       (SELECT tbl   FROM tbl   WHERE tbl_id   = $2))::regclass;
END
$func$;
```

Defend against SQL injection by using [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) and [casting to `regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html).

Comment: @JackDouglas: I built on your example, so you might be interested in this one.

Comment: I found this by chance - the '@' won't reach me if I'm not the poster unless I've commented on the post! Thought you'd like to know :)

Comment: @JackDouglas: Ah, I didn't know that such a comment doesn't reach you. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 7):

You need [dynamic SQL](http://okbob.blogspot.com/2008/06/execute-using-feature-in-postgresql-84.html) - perhaps something like this:

```
create role stack;
create schema authorization stack;
set role stack;

create or replace function f(p_schema in text, p_table in text)
                           returns setof integer language plpgsql immutable as $$
begin
  return query execute 'select value from '||p_schema||'.'||p_table;
end;$$;

create table t1(value integer);
insert into t1(value) values (1);
insert into t1(value) values (2);

create table t2(value integer);
insert into t2(value) values (1);

create table schemas(schema_name text);
insert into schemas(schema_name) values ('stack');

create table tables(table_name text);
insert into tables(table_name) values ('t1');
insert into tables(table_name) values ('t2');
insert into tables(table_name) values ('t1');
insert into tables(table_name) values ('t2');

select f(schema_name, table_name) from schemas cross join tables;
 f
---
 1
 2
 1
(3 rows)
```

I'm assuming that every table is present in every schema as the question implies