# PL/pgSQL regclass quoting of table named like keyword

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, plpgsql, syntax, regclass

I want to create a new table name based on an existing one by appending a suffix to it. A Postgres 9.5 PL/pgSQL function gets the existing table name passed in as `regclass` type and returns the new name as a string. I am using `format()` to construct the new name, and would typically use the `%I` placeholder. This works as long as the passed in table name doesn't match any PL/pgSQL keyword. In this case, no matter what type component I choose (`%I` or `%s`), the quoting is wrong.

Consider the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_name(old_name regclass)
RETURNS text                                           
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS                                    
$$                                                     
BEGIN                                                  
    RETURN format('%I_new', old_name);                 
END;                                                   
$$;
```

Further assume that there are two tables: `treenode` and `overlay`. Calling this function for both results in the following new names:

```
SELECT make_name('overlay'::regclass);
     make_name     
-------------------
 """overlay"""_new
(1 row)

SELECT make_name('treenode'::regclass);
  make_name   
--------------
 treenode_new
(1 row)
```

As it turns out `overlay` is also a PL/pgSQL function (just like `format`, but `treenode` is not), which seems to change quoting behavior. If `%s` is used with `format()`, the result would be `"overlay"_new`. The same happens when I use the `||` operator. If I use `text` as input parameter type, everything works as expected, but I would prefer using `regclass`.

Is there a way to format a string with a keyword-matching `regclass` table name (e.g. `overlay`) without quotes, just like it is the case for a non-keyword matching `regclass` table name (e.g. `treenode`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Explanation

I'm going to step through the multiple layers of misunderstandings one by one - arriving at a simple, secure solution.

0.

The reason why `overlay` is quoted is *not* because it's a function name, but because it's a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).
Also, [`overlay()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) is *not* a "PL/pgSQL function" (nor PL/pgSQL keyword), it's a standard SQL function built into the Postgres core (`LANGUAGE internal`, so C behind the curtains). In fact, PL/pgSQL has nothing to do with any of this.

1.

A simple logic error.

```
format('%I_new', old_name)
```

This would escape any non-standard identifier with surrounding double quotes before *'_new'* is appended and would fail even with `text` as input type. You have to append *'_new'* before quoting the whole of it:

```
format('%I', old_name || '_new')
```

But that still won't work for `regclass`. Keep reading.

2.

It's nonsense to add quotes to a `regclass` variable with `%I`, since its text representation is already quoted automatically where needed. (Similar to `quote_ident()`, but cannot be NULL; since the input is `regclass` it cannot be NULL to begin with.) You would apply it *twice*. Always use `%s` for `regclass` input (the string as is).

3.

`format()` is overkill for this. Just use [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
quote_ident(old_name || '_new')
```

4.

***Most importantly***, as mentioned above, the `text` representation of a `regclass` variable is automatically escaped. That's built into the cast. To get to the raw text, retrieve it from [system catalog `pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) directly. A [`regclass` value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) is just the `oid` of this table internally.

```
SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid = $1;
```

#### Solution

This does what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_name(old_name regclass)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT quote_ident(relname || '_new') FROM pg_class WHERE oid = $1;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

#### Test

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE "sUICiDAL' namE"();
CREATE TEMP TABLE overlay();

SELECT make_name('overlay') AS n1
     , make_name('"sUICiDAL'' namE"')  AS n2;

     n1      |          n2
-------------+----------------------
 overlay_new | "sUICiDAL' namE_new"
```

Note that `overlay_new` is a perfectly legal identifier so it's not quoted.

If you want the name unescaped (no double quotes) just use:

```
SELECT relname || '_new' FROM pg_class WHERE oid = $1;
```

Comment: Aaah! That is one beautiful solution!!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think was to wrap the call to the `format` function in a `translate` as follows:

```
RETURN translate(format('%I_new',old_name),'"','');
```

This post processes the output of the format and strips the " characters out.

I don't know if anybody has a more elegant solution.  I thought of btrim, rtrim etc...but it would need a call to each.

Comment: Thanks, this is of course a usable work-around, but I want to wait a little bit more before I accept this answer. Maybe someone else  has a better solution that wouldn't involve find/replace on the format result.

Comment: Unless you pass it as a text, make_name('overlay'::text), and do a separate check for the table within the function, I think @smbennett1974 has the answer.

Comment: @amacvar: No, no, no. This is backwards in multiple ways. I added detailed explanation in another answer.