# Safely quoting type names to protect against SQL-injection

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, dynamic-sql, sql-injection

How would I quote the type name to protect against SQL Injection. For example, take this

```
SELECT FORMAT('SELECT CAST(%L AS %s);', '5.42', 'int');
                                                 ^ Quote this
```

That works fine, but if `'int'` is instead `''int); DROP DATABASE foo;SELECT ('` you'll have some problems,

```
SELECT FORMAT('SELECT CAST(%L AS %s);', '5.42', 'int); DROP DATABASE foo;SELECT (');
                          format                          
----------------------------------------------------------
 SELECT CAST('5.42' AS int); DROP DATABASE foo;SELECT ();
(1 row)
```

How would I go about casting to a type provided in run time safely with Dynamic SQL? If I use `%I` instead of `%s` I get an identifier (safe-quoting with `"`, but type-names are not identifiers and do not work with double-quotes).

[**Inspired by this answer to *"PostgreSQL alternative to SQL Server’s `try_cast` function"***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203947/2639) provided by [Jasen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/67180/jasen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How would I quote the type name to protect against SQL Injection.

You do not need `format_type()` for the purpose. You may have misunderstood Andrew there. All you need is the cast to `regtype`:

```
SELECT format('SELECT cast(%L AS %s);', '5.42', 'int'::regtype);
```

The `text` representation of the `regtype` value is the standard SQL name and quoted automatically where needed - and the value is cast to `text` implicitly for the concatenation. Demo:

```
SELECT 'varchar(20)'::regtype, 'int'::regtype, '"char"'::regtype;

regtype           | regtype | regtype
------------------+---------+---------
character varying | integer | "char"
```

`format_type()` would only serve to add type modifiers (which are lost in the cast), an orthogonal matter. Related:

- [PL/pgSQL regclass quoting of table named like keyword](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141113/pl-pgsql-regclass-quoting-of-table-named-like-keyword/141680#141680)
- [How to introspect materialized views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127561/how-to-introspect-materialized-views/19147681#19147681)
- [PostgreSQL syntax error in parameterized query on “date $1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Answer (score 0):

RhodiumToad on irc.freenode.net/#postgresql provided the answer using [`format_type()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html)

> type names are sometimes identifiers to be precise, every type has a name which is an identifier, but some types also have parser aliases which are not if you want to accept only valid types, then use `'foo'::regtype` `format_type('foo'::regtype,-1)`  will return a string with the preferred form of the type

So you can do,

```
SELECT FORMAT('SELECT CAST(%L AS %s);', '5.42', format_type('int'::regtype,-1) )
```

At that point, `int` is just a literal.