# Postgres declare table as a parameter for a function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to create a function that operates on a table, for example

```
create or replace function test(t table) 
    returns void language plpgsql as
$func$
begin   
    select * from t limit 10;
end;
$func$
```

Then, I can call the function with any tablename, e.g.

```
select test(myTable);
```

How would I do something like this?

Comment: Please provide a meaningful example. `returns void` and a syntactically incorrect `SELECT` don't make sense. And *always* your version of Postgres. I think there is a solution.

Comment: You could pass an array of a record type

Answer (score 5):

You cannot declare a table as function parameter *per se*, since there are no table variables in Postgres. But there are various ways to achieve what you might want to achieve - which isn't exactly clear yet.

You can "pass" a table as ...

1. ... table name (type `text` or `name`) - especially when tables may not actually exist (yet):

   - [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386034/939860)
2. ... object identifier (type `regclass`):

   - [PostgreSQL: Pass table as argument in function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141419/postgresql-pass-table-as-argument-in-function/141766#141766)
   - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)
3. ... row type of the table (type `anyelement`) using the concept of polymorphism:

   - [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860)

Typically, you end up using dynamic SQL in the function. Be wary of SQL injection vectors. Related:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
- [PL/pgSQL regclass quoting of table named like keyword](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141113/pl-pgsql-regclass-quoting-of-table-named-like-keyword/141680#141680)

The return type depends on your input and what you want to achieve ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do something like that because every function must either

- Be statically typed
- Be declared with a table-alias specifying the types in the query.

So you'll either have to do..

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(t table) 
RETURNS composite-type
AS
  ...
```

Or,

```
SELECT *
FROM test(myTable) AS (x int, y int);
```

But at some point you have to state the types. Alternatively you can return a schema-less type, like `jsonb`.